# Logic to decipher consecutive date ranges

Tags: c#, linq, logic

Say I have a class Slots as follows

```
public class Slots
{
   //Other properties
    .
    .
    .
    public DateTime StartTime{get;set;}
    public DateTime EndTime{ge;set;}
    //Methods
}
```

And I have  `List<Slots>`, what is the most efficient way to determine consecutive Slotgroups?
Consecutive slots are defined as any group of slots which start the next day relative to the previous slot, there is no overlap.
If there is a day gap(no slots on that day in the list) then it should be considered start of another slot group.

```
public List<List<Slots>> GetSlotGroups(List<SLots> slots)
{
    //return  list of slot groups according to logic described above
}
```

Comment: Do you have any overlap periods?

Comment: what is a gap? can you give a sample function input and output?

Comment: modified the question. Is that enough information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple. Sort by `StartTime`, then iterate over the sorted set, if the current item is not consecutive to the previous one, add a new group and make it current. Then simply add the item to the current group.

```
public static List<List<Slots>> GetSlotGroups(List<Slots> slots)
{
    var slotGroups = new List<List<Slots>>();
    using (var e = slots.OrderBy(slot => slot.StartTime).GetEnumerator())
    {
        List<Slots> currentGroup = null;
        Slots lastSlot = null;
        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            var currentSlot = e.Current;
            if (lastSlot == null || currentSlot.StartTime.Date.Subtract(lastSlot.EndTime.Date).Days > 1)
                slotGroups.Add(currentGroup = new List<Slots>());
            currentGroup.Add(currentSlot);
            lastSlot = currentSlot;
        }
    }
    return slotGroups;
}
```

Comment: Is the efficiency of this better compared to yield?

Comment: If you are planning to just `foreach` the return set once, not really. But that's not the point, the implementation above uses minimum property/indexer accessors as well as DateTime operations/comparisons. Everything has a cost. Many people will say these a micro optimizations, but once you asked for the "most efficient way"... :-) The good is that here it doesn't sacrifice the readability (IMO of course).

Answer (score 2):

This kind of operation is best achieved with GetEnumerator.
The following code expects the list to be sorted.

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Slot>> ToGroups(IEnumerable<Slot> slots)
{
    using (var ie = slots.GetEnumerator())
    {
        var range = new List<Slot>();
        while (ie.MoveNext())
        {
            if (range.Count > 0)
            {
                if (ie.Current.Start > range[range.Count - 1].End)
                {
                    yield return range;
                    range = new List<Slot>{ie.Current};
                    continue;
                }
            }
            range.Add(ie.Current);
        }
        yield return range;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please comment the code to explain the logic? How is it dealing with day gaps?

Comment: see the only conditional statement which compares dates

Comment: The condition should be `if (ie.Current.StartDate.Date!=range[range.Count-1].EndDate.AddDays(1).Date)` otherwise, excellent answer, even returning an IEnumerable!

Comment: Robert, the best practice in my experience is to keep the ending DateTime non-inclusive. Otherwise you actially need something other then a DateTime, such as a DateWithoutTime class or an integer day number.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I came up with. I don't know if it's the most efficient, but it's readable and reasonably fast.

```
    public static List<List<Slots>> GetGroups(List<Slots> slots)
    {
        List<List<Slots>> groups = new List<List<Slots>>();
        DateTime? nextDate = null;
        List<Slots> currentGroup = null;

        foreach (var slot in slots.OrderBy(x => x.StartDate))
        {
            //first time through nextDate and currentGroup are null
            //this condition matches the first time through or any time there is a gap in dates
            if (nextDate == null || nextDate.Value < slot.StartDate)
            {
                if (currentGroup != null)
                {
                    //if currentGroups isn't null then we have a completed group
                    groups.Add(currentGroup);
                }
                //start a new group
                currentGroup = new List<Slots>();
            }
            nextDate = slot.EndDate.AddDays(1);
            currentGroup.Add(slot);
        }

        //if there are no items in the collection currentGroup will still be null, otherwise currentGroup has the last group in it still. We finished iterating before finding a gap in dates
        if (currentGroup != null)
        {
            groups.Add(currentGroup);
        }

        return groups;
    }
```

This code keeps track of the next date in the range by adding one to the end date of the previous slot. As we go from slot to slot we append to a temporary list named currentGroup. When our next date is less than the start date of the current slot, we add the current group to the results list named groups and create a new list for our current group. At the end we presumably have some slots in currentGroup for the last group, so we have to add that one as well.

Comment: Edited to explain a little more.

Comment: Sorry deleted my comment by mistake. Wont this give me just one List<Slots> in my list?

Comment: I think you're missing the groups.Add(currentGroup) nested in the foreach loop.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Yes it looks good, let me run some tests. Thanks for your effort on this

Answer (score 0):

The best answer was based on George's code and Roberts comment, but modified to consider having more than one slot on a given day.

```
 protected IEnumerable<IEnumerable<ExamCalendar>>ToBlocks(IEnumerable<ExamCalendar> slots)
    {
        using (var ie = slots.OrderBy(slot => slot.StartDate).GetEnumerator())
        {
            var block = new List<ExamCalendar>();
            while (ie.MoveNext())
            {
                if (block.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (ie.Current.StartDate.Date != block[block.Count - 1].StartDate.Date && ie.Current.StartDate.Date != block[block.Count - 1].EndDate.AddDays(1).Date)
                    {
                        yield return block;
                        block = new List<ExamCalendar> { ie.Current };
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                block.Add(ie.Current);
            }
            yield return block;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What part of your original question proves that this is the "best"? The method signature is different, is not the most efficient implementation and returns incorrect result when empty `slots` argument is passed.

Comment: how is it incorrect when empty? From what i see, it will return null or empty?

Comment: it will return single item containing an empty list.